Can a Dynamodb table be temporarily restricted to readonly access?
I need to run a migration procedure which changes the form of the data in a DynamoDb table. I want to prevent writes from other processes whilst the migration takes place. Can I achieve this without temporarily modifying any IAM policy which allows writes to the table?

You can, by adding an explicit deny resource policy to the table itself.
{
  "Effect": "Deny",
  "Principal": {
    "AWS": [
      "123456789012"
    ]
  },
  "Action": "dynamodb:PutItem",
  "Resource": "*"
}

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/access-control-resource-based.html

You probably want to include dynamodb:UpdateItem, dynamodb:DeleteItem, dynamodb:BatchWriteItem, and dynamodb:TransactWriteItems as well :-)

Thank you Leeroy. How quickly will the deny resource policy take effect? Should I apply the policy then delay before starting the migration process?

The policy should take immediate effect.
